# Express routes & Same Object needed in several files

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I made an web application where all my server side was in the same file.
To be clear, in my "app.js" i had :

- Express routes
- Socket.io events and more...
- Differents objects reacting with pages events

I want to rework that project to do things properly and i started to do that. I have put my routes in different js files like *login.js*,*subscribe.js*, ...  in a **routes** directory.

In my *app.js* I have added the line : `require('./routes')(app);`

I have a *index.js* file in **/routes** where i had placed my "**Express router**" which is managing all my routes.

### index.js

```
module.exports = function (app) {
app.get('/signup', require('./subscribe').get);
app.post('/signup', require('./subscribe').post);
app.get('/', require('./login').get);
app.post('/', require('./login').post);
...
}
```

Is that the correct way to do with routes ?

The problem i meet is that i have an object named `usersConnected {}` that I fill with some properties when a member is logged in, etc...
This object is in my *app.js* file and I can't reach it from the other files like *login.js*...

### app.js

```
// Express routing defined in ./routes/index.js 
require('./routes')(app);

// Globals variables
var usersConnected = {};
var rooms = {};
...
```

### login.js

1. An example of the usage of `usersConnected`

   ```
   // If login and password matches with couple in database
               usersConnected[login] = {
                   games: rows[0].games,
                   kills: rows[0].kills,
                   deaths: rows[0].deaths,
                   statut: "ACCUEIL",
                   adversaire: "NULL",
                   socket: "NULL",
                   wsId: "NULL",
                   room: "NULL",
                   lsid: funcs.computeRandomLsId(64)
               };
   ```
2. And how i export my "route managing"

   ```
   exports.get = (req, res) => {
     if (!req.session.login)
          ...
   }
   ```

   I have some ideas but I think it's the bad way to proceed like exports my object where I need it or put my object alone in a .js file which will be imported, etc...

If you could give me some trails that would really help me.

Edit : I think my problem is the way i manage my sessions, because `usersConnected` contains all informations about all users connected... Maybe i should use **express-session** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you take a look at express-generator: http://expressjs.com/en/starter/generator.html . It provides a quite nice file structure for you to start. Even though it's quite opinionated, I found it very useful when I started and still do.

In the app.js file you will find something like this:

```
...
var routes = require('./routes/index');
app.use('/', routes);
```

This is a bit tedius if you have a lot of routes. Here you have a code snippet to do this dinamically. [gist](https://gist.github.com/ybrodsky/e54792b17b89dc85a5c6acea4d58e077)

Anyway, the point is that the express generator will help you evacuate your doubts and point you in the right direction.